# NumberBox Decimal Formatter Implementation

Tags: c#, winui-3, winui

`I have a listview Control and within it I am using a NumberBox and bind it to a property in a collection, I need the Number Box to show the value as Decimal on UI as well as return in Decimal rather than Double. How can I achieve this?

xaml Code:

```xml
<NumberBox x:Name="nbFeedCost"
    Grid.Column="30"
    IsWrapEnabled="true"
    NumberFormatter="{Binding DataContext.Formatter, ElementName=ngLot}"
    Style="{StaticResource NumberBoxRightAlignStyle}"
    Value="{Binding FeedCost, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

VM code:

```cs
DecimalFormatter Formatter = new DecimalFormatter();
```

and just initialized Formatter in VM code but it is throwing exception saying "Failed to assign the property Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NumberBox.NumberFormatter"`

Comment: WinUI3 and UPW are not the same. Is the question about WinUI3 or UWP? Please edit the tags

Comment: @SimonMourier It is for WinUI3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you base a style off a built-in control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74234027/how-do-you-base-a-style-off-a-built-in-control)

Comment: I can reproduce. Not sure why it doesn't work from XAML. I seems to work by code though.

Comment: @SimonMourier It works if you use a "ViewModel" explicitly.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding I used the DecimalBox as control in my xaml code, but it is rounding off 13 times 9 to 1000000000000 which is the main issue that i need to tackle, that's why want to change NumberBox accepting only double as input.
The number should not be rounded off.

Comment: Sorry. It works with x:Bind outside a DataTemplate but doesn't with Binding.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding - yes, it works with x:Bind but doesn't work with Binding for some reason.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding How can I use it using x:Bind, can you plz give one example for code behind and xaml code

Comment: I posted an answer with a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that `Binding` doesn't work but `x:Bind` works. Not sure why.  Might be a bug in WinUI 3.

This is a workaround that works:

```xml
<Page 
    ...
    xmlns:f="using:Windows.Globalization.NumberFormatting">
    <Page.Resources>
        <f:DecimalFormatter x:Key="DecimalFormatter" SignificantDigits="5"/>
        <!-- You can use bindings if you need to. -->
        <!--<f:DecimalFormatter x:Key="DecimalFormatter" SignificantDigits="{x:Bind ViewModel.SignificantDigits"/>-->
    </Page.Resources>
    <ListView>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <NumberBox NumberFormatter="{StaticResoure DecimalFormatter}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Page>
```

Comment: Since it seems that you also want to align your ``NumberBox`` to the right, check the [NumberBoxEx](https://github.com/AndrewKeepCoding/AK.Toolkit#:~:text=%F0%9F%94%A2-,NumberBoxEx,-%F0%9F%8E%AC) that I published. I created this because right-alignment on ``NumberBox`` is still in [preview](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4697#:~:text=NumberBox%27s%20TextAlignment%20property%20is%20currently%20still%20in%20preview%3A).

Comment: Still when i give 13 times 9, it is rounding it off to 1000000000000, which is the main issue because i dont want it to round off.

Comment: Do you mean that if you enter "13x9" it shows "1000000000000" instead of "117"?

Comment: I mean 9999999999999 gets replaced with 10000000000000

Comment: Oh, sorry. I guess you are hitting the [max amount of digits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types#:~:text=System.Single-,double,System.Double,-decimal) that a double value can handle. Since ``NumberBox`` handles its value as double, you might need to implement a custom control.